# SharePoint Workflow 2010 intermitently creating folders in SharePoint 2016 site

Tags: sharepoint-server, list, workflow, 2016, folder

I have a workflow that generates folders in a separate document library based on information from a task list. I've enabled it to be started manually and when a task is created. However, on certain tasks the workflow pops up with an error:

[image]

I've tried editing it several different ways, to no avail. There is seemingly no sense in which ones it doesn't create, there is no evident similarity that could be causing the error between the items.

Does anyone know a particular reason why this might be happening?

In terms of the workflow, this is what I have:

[image]

In terms of the initial list, it is a task list where things like a task ID, title, due date, assigned to, etc are located. The task library is a document library with folders. The Variable:create4 is where Path and Name are [%Current Item:ID%] - [%Current Item:Task Name], and content type ID is folder. The idea behind it is that whenever a new task is created, a folder is automatically generated in the task library where all related files can be put relating to that task.

Comment: Did you check the ULS logs ? try to log the url of the folder it is trying to create and check.

Comment: Is it only you that is initiating the workflow?  No other user?  (I was thinking about using an Impersonation Step, but if it's only you that's using the workflow then I'd be barking up the wrong tree).

Comment: Karthik, how would I access the ULS logs? Is that the same as the workflow history? And Tally, it is only me using the workflow thus far, and I even added an impersonation step to try and do a work around, but no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up fixing the issue by creating a seperate Task ID and Task Name Column in the Task Library. This allowed for a less complicated string going into the path and name. It works quite well now, I've even fixed the ordering issue by adding a secondary ID column that converts the numbers to have "00" in front to allow for proper numerical ordering. 
Thank you for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can download a [uls viewer](https://www.microsoft.com/en-sg/download/details.aspx?id=44020) to check the ULS log for more information. Here is a tutorial:https://www.petri.com/ulsviewer-sharepoint-2013-logs

The error message shows the issue may due to the action of creating list item failed. Make sure the list exist and user can create list item there. If possible, would you like to share us with your workflow and some information about corresponding lists and libraries?

Comment: Will this ULS viewer work in SharePoint 2016? I'll see if I can download the software anyways.

In terms of the workflow, this is what I have:

Comment: @Sarabi9733 Yes the Viewer works with sp2016

Comment: I have edited my original question to include some further information about the workflow and corresponding lists. I'm going to check the ULS logs today.

Comment: turns out I can't get ULS viewer on my computer (not allowed to download software off the internet). Is there any other way to access these logs?

Comment: @Sarabi9733, If you are not allowed to download software, you can directly check the log file(a bit challenging as you need to check in txt file), The path is C:\program file\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\LOGS. And the workflow seems to be fine. We may need to get more information through log. Or it may be better to contact your IT team

Comment: It looks like there is no LOGS folder within that filepath... I think there might be an issue with certain permissions and such, so I might try and contact IT and see what I can do. Thank you for your help!